# jQuery-UI datepicker without current date?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

The jQuery datepicker always has a default (selectet!) date (.ui-datepicker-current-day). If you don't set one, it uses the current date.

- My application require the user to select a Date
- There should be no initial selection!
- I use the inline (always visible) datepicker because of the better mobile experience.

I'm able to clear the connected input field by: `$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", null);` But this doesn't remove the `.ui-datepicker-current-day` from the calendar.
Removing the class manually on load, works in the first view. But when you change the month and return back, the current date will be highlighted as selected again.

There are a few old bug reports:

- bugs.jqueryui.com: [ticket/7786](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7786) + duplicates: [ticket/8009](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8009), [ticket/8159](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8159)
- drupal.org: [issues/2004216](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker/issues/2004216)

But i'm still unable to find a usefull solution!

Here's a snippet:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({altField: "#date"});
    // remove default date
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", null);
    // remove current-day class (because default date is still highlighted)
    $("#datepicker").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day").removeClass("ui-datepicker-current-day");
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-current-day a {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

DATE:<input disabled="disabled" id="date" name="date" type="text">
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got it now the way you intended, with the today hightlight removed.
I have used CSS to overwrite the highlight class with the style from the normal dates.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({altField: "#date"});
    // remove default date
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", null);
    // remove current-day class (because default date is still highlighted)
    $("#datepicker").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day").removeClass("ui-datepicker-current-day");
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-current-day a {
    background-color: red !important;
}
a.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #454545;
}
a.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight.ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5 !important;
    background: #f6f6f6 !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    color: #454545 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

DATE:<input disabled="disabled" id="date" name="date" type="text">
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this still solves my problem. I will need the highlight classes once the user select one date. In your solution is still a date (today) highlighted when you click the "Next" (month) button and afterwards the "Prev" (month) button (The user didn't click any date in this case).

Comment: Okay It should work now but sorry for the dirtyness. The default highlight (triggered by switching months) has its own class so I overwrote that too and forced it with !important. Hope that helps you.